# How to solve this numbering issue due to overlap?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

The working Codepen demo [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/NWXvVEm?editors=0011). When you click on the grid, it will draw lines with numbered red dots. The problem I am facing now is **: lets say** if you click on the grid to give a 1,2,3 line as shown above and because you want to create a line with dot number 5, **you have to click back on the 2 again**. So, a number gets skipped because it labels it as **1,2,3,5 and there is no 4**. I tried to actually amend the code at Line 160 because it is responsible for the addition of the numbering. Any help will be appreciated .

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('red-dot');
var eLength = elements.length;
kk=0;
  dValue = eLength+1;
```

Thank you for reading and have a nice day :)

[image]

Comment: Have zero idea of what you are talking about. If I clicked on 1 then 2 then 3, as you seem to suggest I do, then have to click on 2 again, then to get any desired results, then this means your "front-end" logic is flawed (logical errors) and your backend result is irrelevant until your front end is solved. ... It's a nice graphic but you clearly are in beyond over your head on this problem.

Comment: It;s not clear what you saying, but by reading your code, i think you want to  have ' + "px"' to lines 166, 167

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. 
Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/) which applies also to any other external resource such as Codepens. Questions always must be self-containign without relaying on external resources.

Comment: @Jasmine please provide a little bit clear explanation of your question so that the community could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resides in `create_dot`. When you compute the next number, you take in consideration all red dots, even those you have hidden :

```js
//line 157
 var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('red-dot');
 var eLength = elements.length;
 kk=0;
 dValue = eLength+1;
```

What I would do is this (avoiding global variables) :

When you set the background to transparent, add a class `hidden` the adapt your selector :

```js
//line 172
if (!isTaken) {
      newDot.dataset['dvalue'] = dValue;
      newDot.innerHTML = newDot.dataset.dvalue;
    } else {
      newDot.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      newDot.classList.add('hidden');
    }
```

Then :

```js
//line 157
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.red-dot:not(.hidden)');
 var eLength = elements.length;
 kk=0;
 dValue = eLength+1;
```

This way, you will only count visible red dots. THis technique can be adapted to fit your needs, you can either filter the elements and check their background-color property too if you prefer. The error is only in the fact that you don't display some red-dots, but you count them anyway and that lead your function to skip numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to introduce a new global variable `numberOfDots`. Initialize it to zero. Increase its value only when a dot is drawn on a grid position that is not already taken, i.e. inside the `if (!isTaken)` block. Then, instead of `dValue = eLength+1`, you can do `dValue = numberOfDots+1`.